# Compiling Doxygen from Sources on Windows

Tags: visual-studio-2012, compilation, cmake, doxygen, doxygen-wizard

I am compiling the doxygen on window from the sources and I have followed this link -> http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/install.html#install_src_windows.
I have done the necessary requirements for installation but I get this error in the root folder when ever I run this command : 
cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 2013"

[image]
Is it looking for the compiler?But basicclr.exe is already there

Contents of CmakeError.log :

```
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
1
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.17929
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.18063]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 7/5/2016 9:53:56 AM.
Project "C:\tools\doxygen-1.8.11\CMakeFiles\3.6.0-rc4\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
C:\tools\doxygen-1.8.11\CMakeFiles\3.6.0-rc4\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj(18,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
Done Building Project "C:\tools\doxygen-1.8.11\CMakeFiles\3.6.0-rc4\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\tools\doxygen-1.8.11\CMakeFiles\3.6.0-rc4\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
  C:\tools\doxygen-1.8.11\CMakeFiles\3.6.0-rc4\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj(18,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.06


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
1
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.17929
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.18063]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 7/5/2016 9:53:56 AM.
Project "C:\tools\doxygen-1.8.11\CMakeFiles\3.6.0-rc4\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
C:\tools\doxygen-1.8.11\CMakeFiles\3.6.0-rc4\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj(18,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
Done Building Project "C:\tools\doxygen-1.8.11\CMakeFiles\3.6.0-rc4\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\tools\doxygen-1.8.11\CMakeFiles\3.6.0-rc4\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
  C:\tools\doxygen-1.8.11\CMakeFiles\3.6.0-rc4\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj(18,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.05


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
1
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.17929
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.18063]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 7/5/2016 9:54:53 AM.
Project "C:\tools\doxygen-1.8.11\CMakeFiles\3.6.0-rc4\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
C:\tools\doxygen-1.8.11\CMakeFiles\3.6.0-rc4\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj(18,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
Done Building Project "C:\tools\doxygen-1.8.11\CMakeFiles\3.6.0-rc4\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\tools\doxygen-1.8.11\CMakeFiles\3.6.0-rc4\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
  C:\tools\doxygen-1.8.11\CMakeFiles\3.6.0-rc4\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj(18,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.04


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
1
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.17929
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.18063]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 7/5/2016 9:54:54 AM.
Project "C:\tools\doxygen-1.8.11\CMakeFiles\3.6.0-rc4\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
C:\tools\doxygen-1.8.11\CMakeFiles\3.6.0-rc4\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj(18,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
Done Building Project "C:\tools\doxygen-1.8.11\CMakeFiles\3.6.0-rc4\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\tools\doxygen-1.8.11\CMakeFiles\3.6.0-rc4\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
  C:\tools\doxygen-1.8.11\CMakeFiles\3.6.0-rc4\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj(18,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.04
```

And of CMakeOutput.log is :

```
The system is: Windows - 6.1.7601 - AMD64
```

Comment: CMake is not able to detect the requested Visual Studio version on your machine. This is a clear indication that you either did not install Visual Studio correctly, or something broke your installation afterwards. Try the 'Repair' option from Visual Studio's installer and see if that solves the issue. Also note that Visual Studio can be installed without any C++ language support. Make sure that you have all the necessary components installed that are needed to compile native Win32 C++ applications.

Comment: is there any other test to detect this?I have been developing many successful applications (currently used in manufacturing) using the same VS.Maybe there is some path setting to do so?Can you replicate this with some test example?

Comment: CMake works out of the box with a fresh, correctly installed VS. If it doesn't work for you, it means something is wrong with your installation of either CMake or VS. Determining what that _something_ is via StackOverflow will be very tedious for both of us. I already gave some hints at how to fix the (in my experience) most common causes for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the "Visual Studio command prompt" from the Tools menu inside Visual Studio? A plain command window does not work.

Comment: Have you tried using an out of tree build with  `mkdir build; cd build; cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 2013" ..`.